# Temporarily redirect the output of Print[ ] to a second file

Tags: scripting, printing

I have started using *Mathematica* to automate file backup operations. The logistics I need make *Mathematica* a good choice. I am testing and developing the Notebook manually, and `Print` outputs document the operational events. The saved Notebook provides a record of the process for that day.

I would like to have an easy way to direct Print output to a separate file, for example, by adding

```
DirectPrintOutputTo["filename "<>DateList["Year","Month","Day"]<>".txt"]
```

at the beginning of a Notebook. The advantages of this approach seem obvious.  I assume I would need to load my function from a package before calling it.  Is something like this this possible?  Any suggestions about how to do it?

Alternatively, maybe I could write a print function called `PrintTo` that would, on first use, open an output file with the name assigned to `printToFileName`, and I could use the editor to change all the `Print` functions to `PrintTo` functions. Not so fancy, but I think I know how to how to do it.

I think that I answered my own question, in the sense that my alternative idea seems straightforward and pretty implementable.

Comment: My current scripting approach used Print statements to print results to the scripting notebook. I don't think PutAppend would work (but I may not understand your suggestion).

Comment: I have missunderstood the question, I thought you are going to write this not to change `Print`. So it is not good suggestion then :)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(5040)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5040/121), [(7081)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7081/121), [(22584)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22584/121)

Comment: I wonder if one could use 'TagSet' to make extend the functionality of 'Print' to your specific needs.  I don't have much time to think through this now (heading away for a week).  May I can work something up later tonight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation for `Print`: "`Print` sends its output to the channel `$Output`."

Therefore you can just do this:

```
$Output = OpenWrite["filename " <> DateList["Year", "Month", "Day"] <> ".txt"];
```

before you run the file.

Something more structured would be like this:

```
stream = OpenWrite["c:/users/gre/desktop/derp.txt"];
AppendTo[$Output, stream];

(* run your file here *)

Close[stream];
$Output = Most[$Output];
```

Since `Print` by default outputs to stdout, you could also pipe the output by running the notebook as a script.

Comment: I tried using `Block[{$Output = ...`, but this didn't seem to work for `$Output`.

Comment: Beat me to the punch about `$Output`. However, I was working on a generic environment.

Comment: @rcollyer Well you *both* beat me, so...

Comment: @rcollyer agreed. usually i go the lazy route :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yea this is quite hilarious. lmao

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I [beat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7741627/198315) both of you a _long_ time ago, and Leonid. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oops. thanks

Comment: Speaking of which, @Mr.Wizard, where's the upvote love?!? :D

Comment: @rcollyer The comments under the answer you linked to made me smile.  As for votes, I've already upvoted your S.O. answer, and I've deleted mine here.  I also now think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @amr, I was very pleased with this simple solution, however, things printed in a subkernel during for instance ParallelDo don't get redirected to the log. Any way to do this? (I asked it as a separate question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174771/redirecting-all-prints-including-those-in-subkernel-to-file?noredirect=1#comment458817_174771).

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend modifying `Print` to redirect the output when it is not necessary. Instead, you can build up a custom solution that suits your needs. I use a variant of the following for logging in my projects and you should be able to tweak them to your application.

```
Clear[logFile, writeLog, showLog];
logFile := "project-" <> DateString[##, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}] <> ".log" &;

writeLog[message_String] := 
    Module[{str = OpenAppend[logFile[]], date = DateString[]}, 
        WriteString[str, StringJoin @@ Riffle[{date, message, "\n"}, "\t"]];
        Close[str];
    ]

showLog := FilePrint@logFile@## &;
clearLog := Module[{str = OpenWrite[logFile@##]}, Close@str;] &
```

Note the use of [`OpenAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenAppend.html) and [`OpenWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenWrite.html) in the above functions. `OpenAppend` creates a new file if none exists, but appends to an already existing file. `OpenWrite`, on the other hand, simply creates a new empty file regardless of whether a file already exists with that name (thus erasing data, which is what we want here).

Since `writeLog` just takes a string as input, you can simply replace your `Print` commands with `writeLog` and it should work fine.

```
logFile[]
(* "project-20130726.log" *)

writeLog["Hello world"];
showLog[]
(* Fri 26 Jul 2013 12:51:31 Hello world *)

clearLog[]
showLog[]
(* crickets *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already built-in; `Print` directs all output to the [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Output.html) channel where a channel is just a list of open streams.  So, to redirect it, simply

```
oldout = $Output;
    strm = OpenAppend["filename "<>DateString[]<>".txt"];    
    $Output = {strm};
```

and to switch it back

```
$Output = oldout;
Close[strm];
```

Assuming you just want an environment where `Print` is re-directed, you could do something like this

```
ClearAll[RedirectPrint];
SetAttributes[RedirectPrint, HoldRest];
Options[RedirectPrint] = {OpenMethod -> OpenAppend};
RedirectPrint[filename_String, body_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{old, strm, open},
  open = OptionValue[OpenMethod]; (* needs error checking here *)
  old = $Output;
      Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        strm = open[filename];
        $Output = {strm},
    body,
    $Output = old;
    Close[strm]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: @Mike the change is good, I was taking the OP's code directly without looking at it ...