# Followup question from "Temporarily redirect output of Print[ ] to a second file

Tags: printing, streams

I'm implementing the first answer to my earlier question about [redirecting the output of Print[ ]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29235/temporarily-redirect-the-output-of-print-to-a-second-file). Opening a file with `OpenWrite[]` and assigning the stream to `$Output` seems to work satisfactorily.  However, `Close[]` gives the error message shown below, and doesn't close the file. Does anyone know what's wrong?  (Print statements and other code goes between opening the output stream and attempting to close it)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with not reassigning `$Output` back to stdout. You could do it by writing your code like so:

```
fname = FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Desktop", "test.txt"}];
Module[{out = $Output},
  $Output = OpenWrite[fname, FormatType -> OutputForm];
  Write[$Output, "The quick brown fox ..."];
  Print[$Output];
  Close[$Output];
  $Output = out]
```

The file written out by this code looks like this:

> The quick brown fox ...
>   OutputStream[/Users/oldmg/Desktop/test.txt, 126]

The file is properly closed and no error messages ensue. However, I don't think that's good practice. I much prefer this approach which makes reassignment unnecessary:

```
Block[{$Output = OpenWrite[fname, FormatType -> OutputForm]},
   Write[$Output, "The quick brown fox ..."];
   Print[$Output];
   Close[$Output]]
```

#### Edit

As rcollyer points out in a comment, it is a good idea have some error handling; in particular, the file should be closed even if an abort should occur between the time the file is opened and the time it is closed.

```
Block[{$Output, rtn},
  rtn = OpenWrite[fname, FormatType -> OutputForm];
  If[rtn === $Failed,
    $Failed,
    AbortProtect[
      $Output = rtn;
      Write[$Output, "The quick brown fox ..."];
      Print[$Output];
      Close[$Output]]]]
```

Comment: Something like this [code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29239/52), maybe?

Comment: @rcollyer. Yes, but I wasn't aware of that post. I neglected to follow the link to it given above. It looks like the OP didn't thoroughly understand the advice given there, so still needs a push in the right direction.

Comment: Likely that is exactly what happened. My only issue with your code is there is no error handling. If an `Abort` is issued, the stream is not closed. This [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1602/52) has a few strategies for handling that.

Comment: Yes, it would be better wrap the file I/O with `AbortProtect`. I'll make an update that does that.

Comment: To toot my own horn, I like [`BlockStream`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1604/52), but there is some evidence that [``Internal`WithLocalSettings``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1603/52) handles most cases, and I tend to use it almost exclusively, now. Definitely something to keep in ones tool chest.