# Redirecting CellPrint output

Tags: notebooks, cells, monitoring

How can I make `g[];` or `h[];` print the same output as `f[];`?  I am trying to capture the output of one function and put it in a document elsewhere, but the `CellPrint` output is not cooperating.

```
f[] := Module[{},
  Print["Bob"];
  CellPrint[Cell["", Background -> Blue, "Print"]];
  Print["Bill"]]

printlist = {};
Block[{Print = AppendTo[printlist, {##}] &,
   CellPrint = AppendTo[printlist, {##}] &}, f[]];

g[] := Map[CellPrint, ExpressionCell[#, "Print"] & /@
    Flatten[printlist, 1]]

h[] := CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[#, "Print"] & /@
    Flatten[printlist, 1]]

f[];
g[];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CellPrint >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html):

In `CellPrint[expr]`:

> *If expr has head* TextCell, ExpressionCell, *or* CellGroup, *it is inserted **unchanged** into the notebook.*

So changing heads `Cell` to `Sequence` in the first argument of `ExpressionCell` works:

```
ClearAll[g, h]

g[] := Map[CellPrint, ExpressionCell[# /. Cell -> Sequence, "Print"] & /@ 
   Flatten[printlist, 1]]

h[] := CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[# /. Cell -> Sequence, "Print"] & /@ 
   Flatten[printlist, 1]]

g[];
```

[image]

```
h[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a) notice that depending on the settings `Print` may be printed to the `MessagesNotebook` while `CellPrint` always goes to the parent notebook.

b) I'm not sure what is the context so I will just leave those links here:

[Can I Print to a different notebook? (within the context of the same kernel)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32889/5478)

[Temporarily redirect the output of Print[ ] to a second file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29235/5478)

c) **the answer**:

The problem is that you are doing `CellPrint @ ExpressionCell @ Cell[...`. Here is what you can do:

```
f[] := Module[{}, Print["Bob"];
  CellPrint[Cell["", Background -> Blue, "Print"]];
  Print["Bill"]]

printlist = {};
Block[{Print = 
    AppendTo[printlist, ExpressionCell[Row[{##}], "Print"]] &, 
   CellPrint = AppendTo[printlist, {##}] &}, f[]];

g[] := Map[CellPrint, Flatten[printlist, 1]]

h[] := CreateDocument[Flatten[printlist, 1]]

f[];
g[];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not wrap [`ExpressionCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionCell) only around [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) calls? For example:

```
printlist={};
Block[
    {
    Print = AppendTo[printlist, Thread[ExpressionCell[{##}, "Print"]]]&,
    CellPrint = AppendTo[printlist, #]&
    },
    f[]
];

g[] := CellPrint /@ Flatten @ printlist
h[] := CreateDocument[
    Flatten @ printlist
]
```

Then:

```
g[];
```

> [image]

and:

```
nb = h[];
CurrentNotebookImage[nb]
```

> [image]

seem to do what you want.