# Can I print to a different notebook? (within the context of the same kernel)

Tags: output-formatting, output

Please imagine a simple loop:

```
For[i=1,i<=100,i++,
  Print[i];
];
```

We can ask `Print[]` to output $(1,2,3,4,...)$ to a different notebook (in the context of the same kernel)?

Comment: You could look up `NotebookWrite`.

Comment: @YvesKlett Sorry, should have found that.

Comment: Not to worry - perhaps someone can help with `Print` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicates / related: [(1041)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1041/121), [(5040)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5040/121), [(7081)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7081/121), [(10456)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10456/121), [(22584)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22584/121), [(29235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29235/121)

Comment: Also this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5734/5 (just change `MessagesNotebook[]` to your desired notebook.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Yves already mentioned, you can easily create and edit notebooks through *Mathematica* commands. A start would be [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooksFromTheKernel.html), which you can find in the Documentation Center under `tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooksFromTheKernel`

Here is a short example printing the `i` values into a new notebook:

```
nb = CreateDocument[];

For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
 SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
 NotebookWrite[nb, 
  Cell[BoxData@RowBox[{"i is now ", ToString[i]}], "Output"]];
]
```

If you want to know how to construct cell expressions, you could just go over any cell in a notebook and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see the underlying structure.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question has been answered, no reason for this question was given. One possible motivation is to be able to discard a lot of diagnostic output, e.g. from an iterative process, by trashing the newly created notebook.

In such a case an alternative could be Dynamic[.], e.g.

```
ClearAll[iter];
Dynamic[iter]
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
    Pause[1.0];
    iter = "i is now " <> ToString[i]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - my reason for asking was that I was interested in printing multiple plots or outputs at different speeds while running a computation.  It became cumbersome to have everything moving around in the same notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have been using.

Any improvements / comments are welcome.

```
(* this opens a notebook file and if notebook exists it CLEARS the contents as well  *)
OpenNB[fname_] := Module[{dir, fns, nb},
   dir = NotebookDirectory[];
   fns = FileNames[FileNameJoin[{dir, fname}]];
   If[fns === {}, (
     nb = CreateNotebook[];
     NotebookSave[nb, FileNameJoin[{dir, fname}]];
     ), (
     nb = NotebookOpen[fns[[1]]];
     SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
     NotebookDelete[nb];
     )
    ];
   Return[nb];
   ];

PrintNB[style_String: "Print", nb_NotebookObject: EvaluationNotebook[], args__] := NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[SequenceForm[args]], style]];
```

**Here is example usage**

```
logNB = OpenNB["log.nb"];
PrintNB[logNB, "Execution Log for: ", NotebookFileName[]];
PrintNB[logNB, "Started at: ", DateString[]];

f[r] = r^\[Gamma]*Exp[-\[Kappa] r];
PrintNB[logNB, "f(r) = ", f[r]]; 
PrintNB["PageBreak", logNB, " "];
PrintNB[logNB, "Hello"];
```

**Here is the output**

[image: output notebook]

Comment: Why would you only have your `NotebookWrite` write out `"Output"` cells...? If you allow your code to pass the style of cell to print (defaulting to `"Output"`) you also won't need to fake the `"Subsection"` or whatever style with  `PrintHeader`...

Comment: @b3m2a1 I wrote the code so that it behaves like Print[], which is what the question asked for.  PrintHeader is just a helper function.

Comment: Well yes, but I'm saying there's a better approach. Also if you want to directly emulate `Print` you should use `"Print"` as the cell style instead of `"Output".

Comment: @b3m2a1 Ok, I changed to `"Print"`.  Would you be able to give an exact replace for the two lines:
 
    `boxes = ToBoxes /@ List[args];`
    `NotebookWrite[nb, Cell[BoxData[  RowBox[boxes]], "Print"]];`

Comment: looks like `Print` does this: `Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[SequenceForm[args]], "Print", CellLabel -> "During evaluation of In["<>ToString[$Line]<>"]:="]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I implemented your suggestions.  It works well from my testing of it.  Could you give a like?